# Spring + Hibernate + WebFlow + Maven. Can`t to get session from SessionFactory using @transactional

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, transactional, sessionfactory

I have tried everything during almost a week, but cannot resolve this problem. When I use sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() my session is not creating automatically (how I understood) and therefore I get exception. Please help me with my trouble.

My DAO

```
    @Component
public class DatingDAOimpl implements DatingDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public List<Dating> datings;


@Transactional
public List<Dating> getDatings() {

    datings = (List<Dating>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createCriteria(Dating.class)
            .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();

    return datings;
}

}
```

my dispatcher-servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<import resource="webflow.xml"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="ru.javabegin.training.springlibrary"/>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry"/>
</bean>


<bean class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"/>
</bean>


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.faces.mvc.JsfView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".xhtml"/>
</bean>


<bean id="msg" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/locales/messages"/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>


<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="ua"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/Library"/>
</bean>


<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>



<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

My hibernate config

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
       "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
      "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property 
 name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tryzub</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<!--<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>-->
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">myname</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">mypassword</property>

<mapping resource="uk.tryzub.entities/Dating.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping class="uk.tryzub.entities.Dating"/>
<mapping resource="uk.tryzub.entities/Post.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping class="uk.tryzub.entities.Post"/>
<mapping class="uk.tryzub.entities.Topic"/>
<mapping resource="uk.tryzub.entities/Topic.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="uk.tryzub.entities/User.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping class="uk.tryzub.entities.User"/>
</session-factory>
```

My flow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">



<view-state id="main" model="datingDAOimpl">

    <on-render>
        <evaluate expression="datingDAOimpl.datings"/>
    </on-render>

</view-state>
```

Finally my exception:

```
        23:47:45,078 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (default task-5) Replacing scope 'request' from [org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestScope@5727d8bd] to [org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestScope@54aa3323]
23:47:45,325 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-6) UT005023: Exception handling request to /tryzubArtefact/app/main: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing [AnnotatedAction@5c540f1a targetAction = [EvaluateAction@632e9ed7 expression = datingDao.list(), resultExpression = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]] in state 'main' of flow 'main' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing [AnnotatedAction@5c540f1a targetAction = [EvaluateAction@632e9ed7 expression = datingDao.list(), resultExpression = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]] in state 'main' of flow 'main' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionList.execute(ActionList.java:154)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.render(ViewState.java:291)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.refresh(ViewState.java:242)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:220)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:537)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:228)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/transaction/spi/TransactionContext
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:544)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:463)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.list(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:112)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:129)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:49)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:342)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:299)
    at org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValue(SpringELExpression.java:84)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:75)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/transaction/spi/TransactionContext
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.isSameConnectionForEntireSession(HibernateTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:445)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.TransactionContext from [Module "deployment.tryzubArtefact.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    ... 78 more
```

Please, help me to understand where is hidden my mistake. Thank in advance

Adding pom.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>tryzub.springtryzub</groupId>
    <artifactId>tryzubflow</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <properties>
        <webflow-version>2.4.1.RELEASE</webflow-version>
        <spring-framework-version>4.1.5.RELEASE</spring-framework-version>
        <springsecurity-version>3.2.6.RELEASE</springsecurity-version>
        <slf4j-version>1.6.1</slf4j-version>
        <mojarra-version>2.2.10</mojarra-version>
        <primefaces-version>5.0</primefaces-version>
        <hibernate-version>5.2.2.Final</hibernate-version>
        <mysqlconnector-version>6.0.6</mysqlconnector-version>
    </properties>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-framework-version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>${mojarra-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${mojarra-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>${primefaces-version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
            <version>${webflow-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysqlconnector-version}</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Comment: You mentioned "When I use sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() my session is not creating automatically (how I understood) and therefore I get exception." What makes you think this is the case? Can you reformat your exception, it is difficult to read.

Comment: Because I checked it using method "session.isConnected()". SessionFactory.openSession works and isConnected is true, but getCurrentSession does not work in all cases I`ve tried

Comment: You exception doesn't seem to indicate any problem with you DatingDaoImpl. You are probably not capturing the real cause of your exception or maybe the problem is elsewhere. Please consider writing a unit testing for getDatings(). It will serve you well.

Comment: When I use Transactional there are not work both methods. Without Transactional method openSession works fine

Comment: And its impossible!  When I create Session by method openSession everything works fine, I can retrieve data from DB. But  SessionFactory.getStatistics() show me 0 opened sessions! How its possible?

Comment: Ok, the exception stacktrace you provided does not include this Hibernate exception. Capture the full stacktrace correctly so that you can get the help you need. Also, turn on debug for hibernate and spring, in whatever you use (log4j?). You know how? Also, you have two other options - using <tx:advice> in your XML config, or doing it programmatically. Trying one of these will rule out any other issues.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue with session. To get over this I imported org.hibernate.session and called sessionFactory.getCurrentSession in every method. Hope this helps.

```
@Transactional
@Repository("supplierDAO")
public class SupplierDAOImpl implements SupplierDAO {

public SupplierDAOImpl() {
}

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

Session ss;

public SupplierDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

public List<Supplier> supplier() {
    ss = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    return ss.createQuery("from Supplier").list();
}
```

Comment: Thank for answer, but it does not resolve this trouble. I have imported org.hibernate.session already.

Answer (score 0):

In your pom.xml you are using hibernate v5, so change this:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

---

**Update:** In the light of new information from you, the following may not be necessary based on whether you DAO can be proxied or not. That remains to be tested by you. But catching the right exception is important, so a try catch recommended.

Also, one thing you should make a note of when using declarative transaction management like you are doing is understand how transactions are [proxied](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained)

So you may want use a separate `Service` class and inject your `DAO` where the transaction management is `declared`, so that it can be proxied. So you would need to use something like a DatingService and call it from your flow.

Try that and see. Also consider renaming methods appropriately if necessary.

```
public class DatingService
{
    @Autowired
    private DatingDaoImpl datingDao;

    getDatings()
    {
        try
        {
            datingDao.getDatings();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //log it please, like so:
            //logger.debug("Exception: ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I will try make my application again from start with Service

Comment: I did like you sad. But it even does not reach to block try-catch, because throws error. Maybe problem is not in Hibernate but its in Spring...

Comment: Ok great. This should be easy to resolve now that you are logging the exception. It's probably due to the version of hibernate you are using. Upload your maven pom.xml file, we can see what is going on.

Comment: Thank. I have added pom.xml

Comment: Today I remake project using entityManagerFactory from JTA instead SessionFactory from Hibernate. But same error...